# bNiceMatrix not compiling unless followed by another bNiceMatrix

Tags: math-mode, matrices, overleaf, nicematrix

I am trying to use Overleaf to make a matrix using *nicematrix*.

This code seems to work and produces the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$$
\begin{bNiceMatrix}

\end{bNiceMatrix}
$$


$$
A = 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[last-row,last-col]
     x_1    & x_2    & x_3    & x_4    & x_5    & \dots  & 1 \\ 
     x_1    & x_2    & x_3    & x_4    & x_5    & \dots  & 2 \\ 
     x_1    & x_2    & x_3    & x_4    & x_5    & \dots  & 3 \\ 
     x_1    & x_2    & x_3    & x_4    & x_5    & \dots  & 0 \\ 
     x_1    & x_2    & x_3    & x_4    & x_5    & \dots  & 0 \\ 
     \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
     1      & 2      & 3      & 0      & 0      & \dots  &   \\ 
    \CodeAfter
        \UnderBrace[shorten,yshift=1.5mm]{7-1}{7-6}{\operatorname{col}(A)} 
        \SubMatrix{.}{1-7}{6-7}{\}}[xshift=1.5mm] 
\end{bNiceMatrix} 
\qquad \operatorname{row}(A)
$$

\end{document}
```

[image]

But when I get rid of the first (empty) bNiceMatrix, I get lots of errors (Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. and Missing $ inserted.) and the matrix comes out totally wrong: [image]

Would really appreciate if anyone knows how to go about this! All of my trouble shooting yielded the same output (including some errors that \UnderBrace and \SubMatrix couldn't work because the matrix was too small).

Thanks so much!

Comment: Clearing `.aux` file should work.

Comment: On first page of `nicematrix` package manual: The idea of `nicematrix` is to create `pgf` nodes under the cells and the positions of the rules of the tabular created by array and to use these nodes to develop new features. As usual with `pgf`, the coordinates of these nodes are written in the **`aux`** to be used on the next compilation and that’s why `nicematrix` may need several compilations.

Comment: Thank you @muzimuzhiZ! I read that and really wasn't sure what it meant, so thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `$$` in latex (but you would get the same error with `\[` here)

`nicematrix` records data in the aux file to get correct measurement data on a later run, but if you delete (or add) a matrix on the same page as an existing one it can use the data for the wrong matrix. If you delete the `aux` file and allow clean data to be written the example runs without error.

Comment: Thank you, David! I had changed from `\[` to `$$` just to see if it would fix anything —— after clearing all the raw files I got it to work.